# How to make user defined URLs?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, smarty

I have a  PHP website created by using  MVC framework I want to change the  urls.these urls depends on pages means In my webpage I have an option for selecting the city based on the city change url want to change.
Now it showing

```
www.legacy.com/womens/tops/
```

here womens is a folder and tops is a php file.
I want to change it as

```
www.legacy.com/womens_tops_in_uk.php
```

or

```
www.legacy.com/ladies_tops_in_uk.php
```

I want to change like this how I can do this?

Comment: actually 1st one is more seo friendly.

Comment: you mean www.legacy.com/womens_tops_in_uk.php this one

Comment: really se's no longer cares about url's

Comment: for seo purpose i need to change the urls

Answer (score 0):

First enable mod_rewrite in Apache in httpd.cfg file located in Apache directory. It'll commented by default , you have to un comment to enable it.

Your URL : www.legacy.com/womens/tops?city=UK
Your Desired URL will be : www.legacy.com/tops_UK

Now write this lines in your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^tops_(.*) womens/tops/id=$1
```